# Change detection isn't run properly in Firefox

Tags: javascript, angular, firefox, polyfills, zonejs

In Chrome, everything works, but in Firefox, the bindings are never updated.

It seems like the problem has to do with `core-js` and/or `zone.js`:

- https://github.com/AngularClass/angular2-webpack-starter/issues/709
- https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/9385

These issues are fixed, but I'm at the latest version of angular (`v2.4.9`) and it doesn't work.

I import `polyfill.ts`, which is:

```
import 'core-js/es6/symbol';
import 'core-js/es6/object';
import 'core-js/es6/function';
import 'core-js/es6/parse-int';
import 'core-js/es6/parse-float';
import 'core-js/es6/number';
import 'core-js/es6/math';
import 'core-js/es6/string';
import 'core-js/es6/date';
import 'core-js/es6/array';
import 'core-js/es6/regexp';
import 'core-js/es6/map';
import 'core-js/es6/set';
import 'core-js/es6/reflect';

import 'core-js/es7/reflect';
import 'zone.js/dist/zone';
```

In `main.ts`. I tried putting the `zone.js` import before the `core-js` imports as suggested in one of the Github tickets, but it does not work.

Is there another polyfill that I need to include or link in my `index.html`?

### **Edit #1**

It seems like it's actually working 50% of the time in Firefox. If I refresh the page, it will render the page correctly every other time. When it doesn't work, absolutely no bindings are working; event callbacks are not executed, `{{ ... }}` bindings are not rendered, etc.

### **Edit #2**

This bug is actually caused by [Polymer's platform.js](https://github.com/Polymer/platform) (polyfills for Polymer) which I am linking in my index.html. If I remove it, the bindings start to work again. I have implemented this [Midi synth](https://github.com/cwilso/midi-synth) in my application and it uses Polymer, which requires `platform.js`. So it seems that there is a conflict between `platform.js` and Angular2 **in Firefox**. Is there a way I can resolve this conflict?

Comment: I have a basic working template that imports only `core-js/es6`, `core-js/es7/reflect` and `zone.js/dist/zone`. Can you try only with this please ?

Comment: @ssougnez It doesn't work :/

Comment: Do you have a working example that illustrates this issue?

Comment: I tried to build a live demo to reproduce this, but failed. I built it with https://github.com/AngularClass/angular2-webpack-starter and insert "platform.js,midi.js,waveshaper.js,synth.js" into it. It works well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since no solutions have been found yet, I have resorted to triggering the change detections manually (when user agent is Firefox) for now.

Usage:

```
import { ApplicationRef } from '@angular/core';
...
constructor(private applicationRef: ApplicationRef) {}
...
setInterval(() => this.applicationRef.tick(), 100);
```

Comment: you didn't mention how you did the detecting user agent as Firefox, which I don't know how to do and would like to know how to do, could you include that please?

Comment: This will cause change detection to run every 0.1s, cause performance issues and lot of problems. Please do not do this, it ruins whole angular change detection paradigm

Answer (score 1):

I have been searching a little.

Apparently, Firefox caches data, hence your problem.

A lot of people seem to be annoyed developing Angular w/ Firefox.

I found this [code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29817892/angularjs-firefox-html-cache), it didn't solve the guy's problem but it should solve yours:

```
$rootScope.$on('$viewContentLoaded', function() {
  $templateCache.removeAll();
});
```

If not, I advise you looking around cache and Angular2